# React-Native: _reactNativeFacebookLogin.FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Im trying to implement [this Facebook-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) for React-Native.

I followed the steps in the README guide but cannot get it to Work.
Every time i try to log in with Facebook I get the following error message:

**EDIT**: Im running the a signed APK

**EDIT2:** The error does only happen with the signed APK - what could that mean?

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeFacebookLogin.FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions')
Unable to symbolicate stack trace: Bundle was not loaded from the packager
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.solopro.dogwood, PID: 5018
com.facebook.react.modules.core.JavascriptException: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeFacebookLogin.FBLoginManager.loginWithPermi
ssions'), stack:
facebookLogin@76454:62
touchableHandlePress@52180:39
_performSideEffectsForTransition@21343:26
_receiveSignal@21259:38
touchableHandleResponderRelease@21033:20
invokeGuardedCallback@15044:12
executeDispatch@14877:38
executeDispatchesInOrder@14900:16
executeDispatchesAndRelease@14354:42
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel@14365:35
forEachAccumulated@15179:12
processEventQueue@14527:19
runEventQueueInBatch@15204:33
handleTopLevel@15215:21
<unknown>@14147:39
perform@16143:16
batchedUpdates@31745:20
batchedUpdates@15373:32
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@14146:28
receiveTouches@14208:48
__callFunction@7706:28
<unknown>@7613:22
guard@7564:3
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@7612:6
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:90)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:78)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:319)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry$ModuleDefinition.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:187)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.call(NativeModuleRegistry.java:62)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeModulesReactCallback.call(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:432)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnableDeprecated.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:193)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Maybe this is even a known issue.

**UPDATE**:
The error is pointing out the function "loginWithPermissions" which is not even available in the android package of `react-native-fbsdk` but only in the iOS package.
I have no idea why this function is being used.
I am using `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(...)` for the FB-Login

Comment: Kill the `JS Server` and run `react-native run-android` again.

Comment: I get this error running a signed APK (Should have added this information in the post, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the questioner had overcome this issue.

Sometimes, if some Facebook libraries (like `fbjs/lib/invariant`) are used in development process, the related lines ***must be marked as comment line*** before building the release apk.